# ADF String to Decimal return NULL value

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an imported CSV file with string values.
In this file there are amounts, of which several lines equal 0,00

I want to create a TotalCA column by adding several fields in my table and convert it to a numeric value.

I use the toDecimal function and the values are all returned NULL and the created column is grayed..

I have done a lot of research and I can't find a solution. Can you help me?

Thank you

Lea

Comment: A little confused ,  does the csv file column data contains "0" , "00" or "0,00"? which is correct?  And you want convert it to numeric?

Comment: Yes, that's right. My CSV file contains several columns, which are amounts. Some rows are enriched with values greater than 0, and others contain "0.00" when it is a zero value.
My goal is to import my source, so my CSV file in string, and inside my data flow use my columns to make sums for example so I want to convert them to numeric (after importing my file).

Comment: If it is easier for you, you can let ADF do the conversion for you. In the Source transformation, click on Projection > "Detect data type". You can set the default numeric format types to convert to using the "Define default format" button.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example csv data if I understand you correctly:
[image]

Like you said, some rows are enriched with values greater than 0, and others contain "0.00" when it is a zero value. Actually, the row data contains different data type, `int` and `decimal`.

For these reason and as I tested, no matter `toDecimal()`, `toFloat()` or `toDouble()`, all of the functions don't work. I use Derived column expression to do the data conversion.

We can't keep these data and only can choose one type of them. If you choose the decimal or float, other rows data would be converted to '11.0', I think that also doesn't you want.

Source Projection: I preset the column type to double:
[image]
[image]

(Decimal can't keep '0.00', it only returns '0')

In one word, the only way is that use String data type to keep the data. And also use String data type to receive the data in sink dataset.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.

[Here is my CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g8wX.jpg)

If I go to the Source Projection module and change the type of my column LFC1_UM01S to decimal this is what I get:

Why are some values considered as NULL?

[To decimal column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNE1a.jpg)